# Runtime error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set even though i did not change my code at all

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I wrote this code, it works well previously but somehow this error appeared all of a sudden.

So according to my code below, i've looked at MyAddress, and it was = Nothing even though there are actual data in the range to look at.

```
For m = LBound(varRngtoFormat, 1) To UBound(varRngtoFormat, 1)
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets(varRngtoFormat(m, 1))
    lngTemp = xLastRow(ws1)
    Set strRange = ws1.Range("C5:C" & lngTemp)
    Set strRange1 = ws1.Range("G5:G" & lngTemp)
    Set strRange2 = ws1.Range("f5:F" & lngTemp)
On Error Resume Next
    For Each rngTemp In strRange
        colTemp.add rngTemp, rngTemp
    Next rngTemp
    On Error GoTo 0

    If colTemp.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To colTemp.Count
            strTemp = colTemp(i)
            dblTemp = 0
            Debug.Print strTemp
            For Each rngTemp In strRange
                If rngTemp = strTemp Then
                    dblTemp = dblTemp + rngTemp.RowHeight
                    Debug.Print dblTemp
                End If
            Next rngTemp
            Set myAddress = strRange.Find(what:=strTemp, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            **myStrAddress = myAddress.Address**
            With ws1
                myLeft = .Columns("A").Left
                myWidth = .Columns("A").Width
                myHeight = dblTemp
                myTop = .Range(myStrAddress).Top
                With .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, myLeft, myTop, myWidth, myHeight)
                    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = strTemp
                    .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
                    .TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
                    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
                    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 16
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                    .Line.Visible = False
                    .Line.Weight = 1.5
                    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                    .Shadow.Type = msoShadow21
                    .Shadow.Size = 0.97
                End With
            End With
        Next i
    End If
    Set colTemp = Nothing
Next m
```

Comment: Is your `xLastRow` function written correctly? Can you include that as well?

Comment: hi braX, this is my xLastRow function: Function xLastRow(ByVal wks As Worksheet) As Long
With wks
    xLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", .Range("A1"), xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
End With
End Function

Comment: the error occurs at this line: myStrAddress = myAddress.Address

Answer (score 0):

> the error occurs at this line: myStrAddress = myAddress.Address – regnerrad 1 min ago

You are getting that error because the code could not find `strTemp` and becuase of that `myAddress` is `Nothing`.

Change the line

```
myStrAddress = myAddress.Address
```

to

```
If myAddress Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Not Found" '<~~ Or whatever message/action you want to show/take
    Exit Sub
Else
    myStrAddress = myAddress.Address
End If
```

**Tip**: Whenever using `.Find`, always check if `.Find` returned anything or not by using `If MyObject Is Nothing`

Comment: hi there, but there is an actual value in the range i specified so why will `strTemp` and `myAddress` be nothing?

Comment: They may be an actual value but it may have a space. Since you are using `xlWhole`, it will try to find an extact match.

Comment: Also check what is the address of `strRange`. Add a messagebox before the `.Find`. Type this `MsgBox strRange.Address` before `Set myAddress = strRange.Find....` This way you will know if your search range is correct or not.

Comment: thanks! i've added the code but there's a mismatch error at this line: `colTemp.add rngTemp, rngTemp`

Comment: Yes  That is a different problem. Is your main problem sorted? Your main problem was the error on line `the error occurs at this line: myStrAddress = myAddress.Address – regnerrad 43 mins ago`

Comment: yes but due to the new error the code didnt get to this line: `myStrAddress = myAddress.Address` so i dont know if it got sorted haha

Comment: Trpe this `MsgBox strRange.Address` after `Set strRange = ws1.Range("C5:C" & lngTemp)`. What do you get?

Comment: i got $C$5:$C$24

Comment: So you address is correct. And you have the On error resume next but you still have the error at `colTemp.add rngTemp, rngTemp`?

Comment: What is the address of `rngTemp` at the time of error. Check if there is a formula which is resulting in an error in that cell.

Comment: hi Siddarth, i found out the root of the error; it was the range of the worksheets that was specified wrongly. thanks for all the help!